# Accessing MySQL using php it give error Query Field my code like that

Tags: php, mysqli

> "checking post is set or not "> "checking post is set or not "
>   "checking post is set or not "> "checking post is set or not "
>   ```````````````````````````

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

//variables
$date = escape_string($_POST['date']);
$po_num = empty($_POST['po_num']) ? 0 : escape_string($_POST['po_num']);
$po_date =  escape_string($_POST['po_date']);
$d_date = escape_string($_POST['d_date']);
$job_code = empty($_POST['job_code']) ? 0 : escape_string($_POST['job_code']);
$job_name = escape_string($_POST['job_name']);
$customer_name =  escape_string($_POST['customer_name']);
$qty =  empty($_POST['qty']) ? 0 : escape_string($_POST['qty']);
$prt_type = escape_string($_POST['prt_type']);
$prt_as_per = escape_string($_POST['prt_as_per']);
$cylinder_brand = escape_string($_POST['cylinder_brand']);
$cylinder_len = empty($_POST['cylinder_len']) ? 0 : escape_string($_POST['cylinder_len']);
$cylinder_circum =  empty($_POST['cylinder_circum']) ? 0 : escape_string($_POST['cylinder_circum']);
$no_ups = empty($_POST['no_ups']) ? 0 : escape_string($_POST['no_ups']);
$no_repeat =  empty($_POST['no_repeat']) ? 0 : escape_string($_POST['no_repeat']);
$prt_mm = empty($_POST['prt_mm']) ? 0 : escape_string($_POST['prt_mm']);
$prt_mic =  empty($_POST['prt_mic']) ? 0 : escape_string($_POST['prt_mic']);
$prt_wt = empty($_POST['prt_wt']) ? 0 : escape_string($_POST['prt_wt']);
$lm1_mm = empty($_POST['lm1_mm']) ? 0 : escape_string($_POST['lm1_mm']);
$lm1_mic =  empty($_POST['lm1_mic']) ? 0 : escape_string($_POST['lm1_mic']);
$lm1_wt = empty($_POST['lm1_wt']) ? 0 : escape_string($_POST['lm1_wt']);
$lm2_mm = empty($_POST['lm2_mm']) ? 0 : escape_string($_POST['lm2_mm']);
$lm2_mic =  empty($_POST['lm2_mic']) ? 0 : escape_string($_POST['lm2_mic']);
$lm2_wt = empty($_POST['lm2_wt']) ? 0 : escape_string($_POST['lm2_wt']);
$lm3_mm = empty($_POST['lm3_mm']) ? 0 : escape_string($_POST['lm3_mm']);
$lm3_mic =  empty($_POST['lm3_mic']) ? 0 : escape_string($_POST['lm3_mic']);
$lm3_wt = empty($_POST['lm3_wt']) ? 0 : escape_string($_POST['lm3_wt']);
$slt_mm = empty($_POST['slt_mm']) ? 0 : escape_string($_POST['slt_mm']);
$slt_len =  empty($_POST['slt_len']) ? 0 : escape_string($_POST['slt_len']);
$slt_direction =  escape_string($_POST['slt_direction']);
$ink_series = escape_string($_POST['ink_series']);
$no_ink = empty($_POST['no_ink']) ? 0 : escape_string($_POST['no_ink']);
$bm_qty = empty($_POST['bm_qty']) ? 0 : escape_string($_POST['bm_qty']);
$bm_size =  escape_string($_POST['bm_size']);
$bm_type =  escape_string($_POST['bm_type']);
$cnt_per =  escape_string($_POST['cnt_per']);
$add =  escape_string($_POST['add']);
$coq_req =  escape_string($_POST['coq_req']);
$ds_dc =  escape_string($_POST['ds_dc']);
$com_rep =  escape_string($_POST['com_rep']);
$remarks =  escape_string($_POST['remarks']);
```

> //prepare query

```
$query = "INSERT INTO job_order(
          po_num,
          del_date,
          po_date,
          job_code,
          job_name,
          customer_name,
          qty,
          prt_type,
          prt_as_per,
          having_change,
          cylinder_len,
          cylinder_circum,
          no_ups,
          no_repeat,
          prt_mm,
          prt_u,
          prt_wt,
          lm1_mm,
          lm1_u,
          lm1_wt,
          lm2_mm,
          lm2_u,
          lm2_wt,
          lm3_mm,
          lm3_u,
          lm3_wt,
          slt_width,
          slt_cut,
          slt_direction,
          ink_series,
          no_ink,
          bm_qty,
          bm_size,
          bm_type,
          ds_cont_person,
          ds_add,
          /*ds_coa,*/
          ds_dc,
          ds_com_rep,
          ds_remarks) VALUES (
          '$po_num',
          '$d_date',
          '$po_date',
          '$job_code',
          '$job_name',
          '$customer_name',
          '$qty',
          '$prt_type',
          '$prt_as_per',
          '$cylinder_brand',
          '$cylinder_len',
          '$cylinder_circum',
          '$no_ups',
          '$no_repeat',
          '$prt_mm',
          '$prt_mic',
          '$prt_wt',
          '$lm1_mm',
          '$lm1_mic',
          '$lm1_wt',
          '$lm2_mm',
          '$lm2_mic',
          '$lm2_wt',
          '$lm3_mm',
          '$lm3_mic',
          '$lm3_wt',
          '$slt_mm',
          '$slt_len',
          '$slt_direction',
          '$ink_series',
          '$no_ink',
          '$bm_qty',
          '$bm_size',
          '$bm_type',
          '$cnt_per',
          '$add',
          /*'$coq_req',*/
          '$ds_dc',
          '$com_rep',
          '$remarks'
          )";
```

> // exicute query into mysql

```
$result = mysqli_query($connection,$query);
      confirm_query($result);

      if ($result) {
        $_SESSION['msg'] = "Added New Job Order Successfully.";
        redirect_to('index.php');
      }else{
        echo "Sorry there were some problem.";
      }
  }
```

> it's full php code please check it and find out the error...

Comment: What is your problem here?

Comment: Since you give no detail at all... Check that each column you wrote has the corresponding value in the query (no... I guess noone else will do the counting for you). Also, are those variables escaped? If not there may be the issue.

Comment: I'm 200 sure the column names is right.. and also i've esacped all feilds value,

Comment: add details, what you want and what is output, if error then provide error description

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i probably not guess what is the issue with you and your code but i wanna suggest you to use alternet syntax this make more sense writing very long query.

```
"INSERT INTO table_name SET 
    column_name = $value,
    column_name = $value,
    column_name = $value,
    column_name = $value,
    column_name = $value,
    column_name = $value";
```

Answer (score 1):

Sayed, remove `;` from your query, which is with `'$remarks';`. I feel your query will run, you are getting this issue due to placement of terminator in wrong place.

Comment: i simply cheching error like that   `$rslt = mysqli_query($connection,$sql);`  
`if(!$rslt) Die( 'Query feild' );`  
and it give me query feild error..

Comment: To test your query just print $sql and run in your db/phpmyadmin

Comment: yes i've try in phpmyadmin but in there it's works fine.. i'm very upset why i get this error.

Comment: Syed now you have error with your php code, update your question and share the php code as well to get it fix.

Comment: Ram Sharma Here is edited full php code Please Check it and Figure It Out.. thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = "INSERT INTO job_order( po_num, del_date, po_date, job_code, job_name, customer_name, qty, prt_type, prt_as_per, having_change, cylinder_len, cylinder_circum, no_ups, no_repeat, prt_mm, prt_u, prt_wt, lm1_mm, lm1_u, lm1_wt, lm2_mm, lm2_u, lm2_wt, lm3_mm, lm3_u, lm3_wt, slt_width, slt_cut, slt_direction, ink_series, no_ink, bm_qty, bm_size, bm_type, ds_cont_person, ds_add, ds_coa, ds_dc, ds_com_rep, ds_remarks) VALUES ( '$po_num', '$d_date', '$po_date', '$job_code', '$job_name', '$customer_name', '$qty', '$prt_type', '$prt_as_per', '$cylinder_brand', '$cylinder_len', '$cylinder_circum', '$no_ups', '$no_repeat', '$prt_mm', '$prt_mic', '$prt_wt', '$lm1_mm', '$lm1_mic', '$lm1_wt', '$lm2_mm', '$lm2_mic', '$lm2_wt', '$lm3_mm', '$lm3_mic', '$lm3_wt', '$slt_mm', '$slt_len', '$slt_direction', '$ink_series', '$no_ink', '$bm_qty', '$bm_size', '$bm_type', '$cnt_per', '$add', '$coq_req', '$ds_dc', '$com_rep', '$remarks' )";
```